# What is the ideal volume distribution for minimization of transonic drag?

Tags: aircraft-design, drag, transonic

I am aware what the area rule states - my question is what is defined as "as smooth as possible area distribution" - Is there a formula for the curve?

Answer (score 4):

Since Drag is proportional to S'', the key is to derive a shape that has a minimum S''.

The result is the [Sears-Haack body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sears%E2%80%93Haack_body).

> The **Sears–Haack body** is the shape with the lowest theoretical wave drag in supersonic flow, for a given body length and given volume.

The area is given by:

$$ S(x) = \frac {16V}{3L\pi}[4x(1-x)]^{3/2} = \pi R_\text{max}^2[4x(1-x)]^{3/2}$$

And the radius is given by:

$$ r(x) =  R_\text{max}[4x(1-x)]^{3/4} $$

[image]
[Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sears%E2%80%93Haack_body#/media/File:Sears-Haack.png)